# Google Play -505 install error

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

I have an app in Google Play, which was built with tools and API 22. Everything was working well, but last update with API 23 (tools 23.1) shows users with Android 6.0 error numbered "-505" (in Google Play app or in notification). BUT.. its really random... I know about two same devices - Nexus 5 with 6.0.1 - one have -505, second is installing update without problem....

After a lot of searching I've found information that this error means duplicated permission, but which...?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<!-- GCM -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission
    android:name="com.dummy.mobile.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.dummy.mobile.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<android:uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<android:uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<android:uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

ANY ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answer useful for every app developer who is using Android Studio with Gradle and external libraries. Some are affected, some not, but for example **Google-Play-Services** (in current 8.4.0 version, in my case) are involed, and this lib is pretty popular...

**Description:**

Every app **have** to declare own **`applicationId`** in Gradle, and also **`packageName`** in manifest, but this is required by Android Studio. Gradle is **not** forcing `applicationId` to be declared, but it should, beacuse some of libs are using reference `${applicationId}` in their declarations, for example from above mentioned GPS:

```
<provider
      android:authorities="${applicationId}.google_measurement_service"
      ...
```

When you don't have declared `applicationId` build system use libs appId and after apk creation above provider will be:

```
<provider
     android:authorities="com.google.android.gms.measurement.google_measurement_service"
     ...
```

And it will be installed in system with `your.lovely.app` without problem. Real problem will be when another, second app `this.app.will.have.minus505` will be using same library and also created without `applicationId`. In this app there is also same package (in GPS sample com.google.android.gms...) and this is duplication error numbered -505, cause [`authorities` field must be unique](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=784)... If you declare in your app `applicationId` above sample will be:

```
<provider
      android:authorities="your.lovely.app.google_measurement_service"
      ...
```

And this will be unique for shure in whole system as it should be :) Note that reference `${applicationId}` might be also declared in other must-be-unique-in-whole-system fields, which are for example [permissions](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1668), which can't duplicate also.

In my case: Google-Play-Services and Google Cloud Messaging lib (as I know for shure v 8.3 and 8.4). Above sample first snippet is from push messages provider. My app after lib update from 7.x (this version is not using appId reference, maybe `${packageName}` instead?) to 8.4 (using appId ref) started crashing installation with -505 on devices, which already have installed another app (not related with my at all) which also misses `applicationId` declaration and uses same GPS lib. First installed app "reserves" original Google Cloud Messaging provider `authority` field using its "original" lib `applicationId` (cause app's/developer's missing) and this field must be unique in whole system, so my app (as installed after) is getting -505...

**Solution:**

[Here is doc with proper declaration of both packageName and applicationId.](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html) Define this field in your app and it will never "interferre" with another app (really own provider unique in system).

**Homework for advanced:**

Decompile or just "guess" anothers app `Provider` (or any other should-be-unique creature) and declare it in your own app. You may not use it at all, but it probably lock installation of this original app. Seems like pretty good method to lock installations of competitors (e.g. biggest rival). Didn't tried, hope this possibility is "solved" already...

Comment: To clarify, Gradle injects the applicationId into the generated manifest file.  Look at build/intermediates/manifests to see your generated manifest file. All you need to do to fix this is provide an applicationId in your build.gradle file

    `defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your.app.id"
    }`

The Android Vine app actually isn't doing this properly, so you can test locally by installing Vine and your app to see if you get a 505 error. [Take a look at this bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189079)

Comment: like you say. I know that Gradle is injecting this field, but external libs (like GPS) don't see this, dunno why... Only manual declaration (my link in last paragraph, your short answer) is helping. I was interfering with Houzz app (>5mln downloads), already sent feedback, but replies are from templates... :/

Comment: Beautiful answer, saved my butt.

Comment: This is amazing @snachmsm, you saved me. All I could find about the -505 error code were Android 5.0 bugs that were fixed in 5.0.1. Just got this error on Android 6.0 so was wondering what was wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint. I had forgotten a `android:authorities="com.example.android.datasync.provider"` line in AndroidManifest.xml. Changing to `android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"` seems to have solved it.