# Users cannot update/install my app from Google Play(error -505)!

Tags: android, google-play, apk, updates

I uploaded an update to Google Play and it seems many people cannot update or reinstall. When they try to update, they get error something with number `4`, if they try to clean install it, they get error `-505`. I just tried it on emulator and it worked fine, what the heck? Many people report an error. What is wrong?

Comment: just clear the data of play store app and restart the play store app

Comment: but I can't write this in the description, right? Could it be an apk problem? When will it get fixed automatically?

Comment: No its not an APK issue. I think it will only happen on android L devices

Answer (score 1):

There is a great answer on Stack Overflow about error -505 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34959116/4230345).

If that doens't solve your issue, perhaps [this article](https://www.androidpit.com/how-to-solve-google-play-store-errors) may help:

> ### Google Play Store Error Code 505
>
> **Problem**
>   Two or more apps with duplicate permissions
>
> **Solution**
>   You need to find out what app has the same permissions as the one you're trying to install and uninstall the problem app. To do this, find the APK file for the app you are trying to install and attempt to restore the app using a Lucky Patcher backup. The tool should present a window alerting you to which app is producing the conflict. This is the app you need to uninstall.

The article also includes information on other errors such as ones containing '4', as you mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Some of your libraries may be using the `applicationId` variable in their declarations. Make sure you specify the package and the application ID correctly in each of your build.gradle files as described here. https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename

```
android {
  defaultConfig 
  { 
     applicationId "com.app.mine" 
  }
}
```

Further description in this bug report: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189079

Answer (score 0):

This copy of software is corrupted and is not safe to use.
To fix this error, uninstall your copy and do a clean install of this app from an official source (e.g. Google Play).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).